# How to add 5 cells consecutively after an interval of 5 cells in a row of 200 cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row of 200 cells. I have to add/average first five cells (A:E), and then take a break of 5 cells and then add/average second five cells (K:O) and so on till the end of the row. How can I do this?

I have tried doing it manually. Actually, I can do this manually but wanted to know if I can do this automatically.

Comment: We got a doubt. Do you mean you want to get **one** average of **all numbers** that are in first five cells (A:E), and then take a break of 5 cells and then add/average second five cells (K:O) and so on till the end of the row? Or do you mean you want a formula that gets average of five first numbers, drag down to right, skip 5 cells, and then again average of next 5 cells?

Comment: I want an average of first five cells, skip next five cells and then an average of second five cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a test making some faking data like this:

[image]

It's just a bunch of numbers from A1 to CB1. 80 numbers in total. 5 first numbers are `1`, then next 5 are `2`, next 5 numbers are again `1`, then next 5 numbers are again 2, and so on.

This mean that there are 80 numbers, where 40 are `1` and 40 are `2`. I want to get the average of first five cells (A:E), and then take a break of 5 cells and then average second five cells (K:O) and so on till the end of the row. In other words, I want to get the average of the 40 cells that contains a 1 value, and it should return a 1.

For this, I've used an array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(VALUE(RIGHT(COLUMN(A1:CB1);1))<6;IF(VALUE(RIGHT(COLUMN(A1:CB1);1))>0;A1:CB1)))
```

> **NOTE:** Because this is an array formula, it must be inserted pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> instead of
>   only <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, or it won't work!

*How this works?*

You want to sum/average only values that are in columns where last digit of column number is 1 to 5, this means columns 1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25, and so on. So this works this way:

1. The part that says `COLUMN(A1:CB1)` will get an array of column numbers.
2. `RIGHT(COLUMN(A1:CB1);1)` will get last digit of each column number, but **as text**
3. `VALUE(RIGHT(COLUMN(A1:CB1);1))` will convert that last digit into a number.
4. Then with both IFS, we get an array of only those values where last digit of column number is >0 and <6, and we get the average. I get as result of my average `1` and it's true, because the average of 40 times 1 is equal to 1.

Hope this works for you. You can adapt this easily to make it work with 200 cells.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted the question :)

Comment: Thanks :) Your solution worked for me. Your explanation made it better :)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

[image]

In `A2` put:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),10)=1,AVERAGE(INDEX(1:1,,COLUMN()):INDEX(1:1,,COLUMN()+4)),"")
```

Drag right.

Comment: I think I got the wrong interpretation, and yours fits indeed better, lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT to add the amounts in the columns and divide by 100:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISEVEN(INT((COLUMN(A1:GR1)-1)/5)),A1:GR1)/100
```

if you do not always have 200 numbers you can make the `100` more dynamic with another SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISEVEN(INT((COLUMN(A1:GR1)-1)/5)),A1:GR1)/SUMPRODUCT(ISEVEN(INT((COLUMN(A1:GR1)-1)/5))*(ISNUMBER(A1:GR1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

this function have CTRL+SHift+Enter and drag this function until your last data   `IF(OR((RIGHT(COLUMN(A5),1)+0)={1,2,3,4,5}),A5,--FALSE)` 
You Find The Columns only which end `(1,2,3,4,5)` , in last. You use `Sum` function For Add.